# How to change bell sound ("\a") in windows 10

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, char

I was just wondering is there any way on **windows 10** to **change bell** ("\a") sound?
(*I'm using C++*)

Comment: Edit: @πάνταῥεῖ nope, not with windows 10, the sound comes out of the speaker, if an audio device is present and audio drivers are running else it will use hardware buzzer(if present on the motherboard) to generate beep, in that case not possible to change the sound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a method to modify the sound of beep in Windows 10 but not by using `\a` but by using `Beep()`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<windows.h>
main()
{
   Beep(600,600);
}
```

Function parameters `Beep(Freq_in_Hertz, Time_duration_for_sound);`

If you want to stick with `\a`, you may be able to modify its sound by going to sound settings and change the alert sound.

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/utilapiset/nf-utilapiset-beep)

Comment: As the link does not relate to any type of programming, I am mentioning the steps to change the alert sound in Windows 10 here: [Link](https://pureinfotech.com/change-notifications-sound-windows-10/)